# Solve recursion $a_n=a_{n-1}-6\cdot3^{n-1}$ for $n>0, a_0=0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$a_n=a_{n-1}-6\cdot3^{n-1}$ for  $n>0,  a_0=0$

So I calculate first terms

$a_0=0$

$a_1=-6$

$a_2=-24$

$a_3=-78$

I don't see any relation so

$a_n=a_{n-1}-6\cdot3^{n-1}$

$a_{n-1}=a_{n-2}-6\cdot 3^{n-2}$

. . .

$a_2=a_1-6\cdot3^{1}$

$a_1=a_0-6\cdot 3^{0}$

Not sure what to do next, Wolfram solves it in this way:

$a_n=-3\cdot(3^{n}-1)$

How do I get to this point?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you mean $a_n$ or $an$?

Comment: Hello, yes I meant first option, didn't know how to do it in tex, sorry.

Comment: it's just `a_{n}, a_{n-1}`, &c. If there's only 1 character in subscript, the braces are not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$a_n=a_n=a_{n-1}-6\cdot 3^{n-1}=a_{n-2}-6\cdot 3^{n-2}-6\cdot 3^{n-1}=\dotsm,$$
so you can prove with an easy induction that
$$a_n = a_0-6\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3^k=-6\frac{3^n-1}{3-1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

hint...consider $$\sum_{r=0}^{r=n}(a_{r+1}-a_r)=\sum_{r=0}^{r=n}-6\cdot3^r$$

The LHS is a telescoping series and the RHS is a geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for all $n$ we have $$a_{n+1}-a_n = -6\cdot 3^n $$

so we have also: $$a_n-a_{n-1}=-6\cdot3^{n-1}$$

thus $$a_{n+1}-a_n = 3(-6\cdot3^{n-1}) = 3(a_n-a_{n-1})$$

{or divide this two equations:  $${a_{n+1}-a_n \over a_n-a_{n-1}}= {-6\cdot 3^n\over -6\cdot3^{n-1}} = 3$$}

so you have to solve linear recurrence:

$$ a_{n+1}-4a_n+3a_{n-1}=0$$

CAn you do that?

Comment: ok so:

$x^{2}-4x+3$


$\Delta =4$


$x1=1$  $x2=3$

Now I use following formula

$a_n=ar^{n}+br^{n}$

$a_0=0=a+b$

$a_1=-6=a+3b$
$a=-b$   $-6=2b$
$b=-3$    $a=3$
$a_n=3*1^{n}-3*3^{n}$

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: Yeah, I am getting correct numbers for a1, a2, a3 etc.
Though I am still not quite sure how you achieved linear recurrence form, could you expand on that? (Sorry for lack of new lines in above comment, in my original post newline worked correctly)

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: I understand whats happening in 2 first lines, unfortunately after that I am lost.
 $a_(n+1)-a_n=-6*3^{n}$ so how come in the third line first '3' before the bracket appears out of nowhere?

Comment: What about now?

Comment: I mean, I understand lines you add, but still got no idea how to get linear recurrence from that later. Is it dumb of me that I can solve linear recurrence but can't mold it in the first place?

Comment: Just put first and last expression on one side, so you get 0 on other side

Comment: Ohh I see now that, was silly of me. I might pass my exam tomorrow thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a Geometric Series:

$$a_n=-6\sum_{i=1}^n3^{i-1}=-6\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}3^i=-6\times \frac {3^n-1}{3-1}=-3\times (3^n-1)$$